# How to input Chinese in dia

Tags: dia, fcitx

My environment: Ubuntu 18.04

`dia` is a wonderful tool to draw flowchart. While I cannot input Chinese in box. I have tried `fcitx` and `ibus` and both failed.

Someone has prompt a method that edit script `dia`. But after `dia` upgrade，there is no `dia-normal` anymore.

Please help me. Any advise will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch you input methods to x input method after starting Dia.

> Right click in a text box and select "Input Methods" -> "X Input
>   Method" from the popup menu

Or you can set GTK_IM_MODULE environment before start dia.

> env GTK_IM_MODULE=xim dia

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 18.04.4 environment:

`~/.config`is located under `/home/[your user name]/.config`

rm -R ~/.config/fcitx

reboot then everything works